# No appropriate default constructor available on struct

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

**Disclaimer:** I have looked at other questions that could be familiar to this situation however I have found no solution

**Situation:** I am attempting to create a linked list of the type Levelnode (a struct). upon creating the new node it should create a new level (level class).

**Problem:** I receive an error on line 18 (The .cpp file, not the header file) with -

```
Error   2   error C2512: 'Levelnode' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\timi\desktop\ludum dare\ld27\nodes.cpp 18  1   LD27
```

I do have a default constructor in the header file so I really don't see why this error is occuring.

here is the Nodes.h header file:

```
    #ifndef NODES_H
#define NODES_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "structs.h"
#include "Level.h"


using namespace std;

class Nodes 
{
    private:

        Levelnode * p;
        Level * level;

    public:
        Nodes()
        {

        }

        ~Nodes();
        Levelnode * CreateNode(Level * newLevel, SDL_Surface *screen1, string levelName, SDL_Rect camera1);
        void InsertAfter(Levelnode * p, Levelnode * newNode);
        Levelnode * InsertFirst(Levelnode * p, Levelnode * newNode);
        void DeleteNode(Levelnode * p);
        void PrintList(Levelnode * p);
};
#endif
```

here is the .cpp file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Nodes.h"
#include "structs.h"
#include "Level.h"


    Nodes::~Nodes()
    {


    }

    Levelnode * Nodes::CreateNode(Level * newLevel, SDL_Surface *screen1, string levelName, SDL_Rect camera1)
    {
        Levelnode * newNode;
        newNode = new Levelnode;
        level = new Level(screen1, levelName, camera1);
        level->draw();
        newNode->L = *newLevel;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    void Nodes::InsertAfter(Levelnode * p, Levelnode * newNode)
    {
        newNode->next = p->next;
        p->next = newNode;
    }

    Levelnode * Nodes::InsertFirst(Levelnode * p, Levelnode * newNode)
    {
        newNode->next = p;
        return newNode;
    }

    void Nodes::DeleteNode(Levelnode * p)
    {
        Levelnode * pTemp;
        while ( p != NULL)
        {
            pTemp = p;
            p = p->next;
            delete pTemp;

        }
    }

    void Nodes::PrintList(Levelnode * p)
    {
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            p->L.draw();
            p = p->next;
        }

    }
```

struct header file:

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "Level.h"

using namespace std;

struct position
{
    int x;
    int y;
};


struct Levelnode
{
    Level L;
    Levelnode * next;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This means that `Levelnode` does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Please include the source for Level.h, which I'm guessing has the declaration for the struct Levelnode (otherwise, include that header)

Comment: The declaration for the struct is within another header file called structs.h, which I have included within Nodes.h and Nodes.cpp

Comment: Sorry, I meant please show us the source for (now) structs.h, not "#include".  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: source for structs.h has been added :)

Comment: Now we need to see the code for the default constructor for Level, since it is a member of Levelnode, and Levelnode does not have a constructor to call a specific instance constructor for Level.

Comment: You will also need to include Level.h from within structs.h in order for anything that includes structs.h to compile (or make sure that anybody including structs.h includes Level.h BEFORE structs.h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that since your `Levelnode` struct:

```
struct Levelnode
{
    Level L;
    Levelnode * next;
};
```

has a `Level` member, and `Level` lacks a default ctor, the default, compiler-generated ctor for `Levelnode` cannot initialize the Levelnode::L member. The result is that the compiler does not actually generate a default `Levelnode` ctor at all. If you try to create a `Levelnode`:

```
Levelnode node;
```

you will get an error about `Levelnode` not having a default ctor.

You need to provide your own default ctor for `Levelnode` which should initialize Levelnode::L using an appropriate `L` ctor. Like:

```
struct Levelnode
{
    Level L;
    Levelnode * next;

    Levelnode()
        : L(ctor arguments)
    { }
};
```

Another solution would be to provide a default ctor for `Level`, if that makes sense for that class.

Comment: The wierd thing is, Levelnode is a struct, not a constructor

Comment: @TimOgunmakin Structs are the same as classes. The only difference is that their members are public by default, while in classes they're private. There's no other difference. If you post the Levelnode struct, we might be able to see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: okay thanks, I've now included the Levelnode struct below the other classes

Comment: @TimOgunmakin I changed the answer with a likely cause for the problem.